# Best Practice Approach to Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ide

I've been fiddling around with bootstrap for some weeks now and I'm feeling like running in a maze.

There is thousands-and-millions of programs to help you visually building up a bootstrap website, I took a look at various options like: blocs app, rapid weaver, pine grow and some web apps now but I didn't find a solution that makes me confident.

I'm not that into coding, I can do some html, css and low-level php-programming but getting into this framework was not manageable for me while studying and working. As a designer my first approach was using those "visual apps" and to a certain point they can be nice.

Would it be easier to use an IDE and is there an IDE, that can handle bootstrap in a way I don't have to read all the docs to understand what I have to do just to create a simple page?

I'm just searching for the right tool to work with the bootstrap framework and would like some advice from more experienced users - thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the ide for the bootstrap if you want to use the bootstrap you should include the bootstrap css and js files into your project and you can use in your project

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's the way when using an IDE like NetBeans. My Question was, if there is a better program to just setup some bootstrap framework website without the need to code.

Comment: Ok I won't search anymore, there is no "easy way". I suppose the best way from the things I know is to get into the code and use an IDE like netbeans or better webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Bootstrap Studio.  They provide a guy to build bootstrap projects.

https://bootstrapstudio.io/